# How to set default for a column using alter in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am stuck at defining a default value to a already created column.

I created a column and didn't set a default in it but later I realized that I should have set default in it using alter. So I tried but failed searched every where but not found the solution.

Here is the code

```
create table stock
( 
    item_name varchar(200),
    item_code varchar(50),
    Price int,
    availabilty varchar(20),

    constraint i_n unique(item_name),
    constraint i_c primary key(item_code)
)
```

Now after adding some data into it using `insert into` I am not able to add default constraint in price column.

Help me please how to add default constraint in price column using `alter`

IF I add a constraint like this

```
alter table stock
add constraint ID default '' (price)
```

ssms detect it as a error and says

> Msg 142, Level 15, State 2, Line 0
>   Incorrect syntax for definition of the 'TABLE' constraint.

I am using SQL Server 2008

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Stock
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Stock_Price DEFAULT(0) FOR Price
```

Since `Price` is an `INT` column, you *cannot* define `''` as its default - it has to be a valid `INT` value!

Comment: Thank you SIR. you solved my problem. Now it is a working code. God bless you.

Comment: One more question. Is it possible to apply this default for more than one columns ? I mean the same default  ID for more than one columns

Comment: @WaqarAdilMughal: no - if you need that, you have to create a default constraint for each column separately